# "Не()охота": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Когда говорят "не()охота" в значении "лень", частица не- пишется слитно или раздельно? Мне в тексте попалось слитно, но правильно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова с частицей НЕ пишутся слитно, если нет противопоставления и данное слово можно заменить синонимом без НЕ, значит, в Вашем предложении слитное написание.